# Javascript uncaught type error; property can't be read, undefined variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to fetch the value from text input in HTML to a variable in javascript.
An uncaught type error had appeared.
The following are my HTML code:

```
 <form name="purchaseform" id="formma">
 KJW M700 <br>
 <input name='buyM700' type='text' id='1234'>
 <input name='caller' type='button' value='click here' onClick='call()'>
 </form>
```

The following are my Javascript code:

```
var m700 =  document.purchaseform.buyM700.value;
function call() {
  confirm (m700);
};
```

Thank you for helping me in advance.

Comment: did you refer the js file to the html file? eg:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="textscript.js"></script>`

Comment: Where is your JavaScript? In the `<head>` or `<body>`? If in the `<body>`, does the `<script>` element come before or after your `<form>`?

Comment: @Xufox nothing wrong with using [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

Comment: @Phil I wasn’t referring to `document.forms`. Apparently `document.purchaseform` actually works…

Comment: @Xufox ah yeah, for *named* elements.

Comment: why not  document.getElementsByName("buyM700")[0].value

Answer (score 1):

Try following code, your variable declare before call the function when field is empty:

```
function call() {
  var m700 =  document.purchaseform.buyM700.value;
  confirm (m700);
};
```

Comment: Not the cause of the error but this should fix it and also make the `call` function make **much** more sense :)

Comment: In my console I'm not getting this type or error.

Comment: What I meant was the field being empty would not cause the error. It's highly probable OP's JS code runs **before** the element(s) exist. Moving the DOM code into the `call()` function as you have done solves this problem.

Comment: Yes @Phil you asked about this point but Vladimir dose not reply in above :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the form via the forms HTMLCollection of the document

```
var m700 =  document.forms.purchaseform.buyM700.value;
function call() {
  confirm (m700);
};
```

Comment: It's an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an array

Comment: corrected, thank you

Comment: Given `document.purchaseform` [*should work*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321000/javascript-uncaught-type-error-property-cant-be-read-undefined-variable#comment81593186_47321000), I doubt this is the problem